# Find A Particular Integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to find the particular integral for the equation:

$$P(D)y=Q(x)=x+e^x$$

My initial thought was to use $(PI)(x)=y(x)=ax+bxe^x$ but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

Here's the full question:
[image: Full Question]

Comment: Is there meant to be a derivative somewhere? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I've added the full question above! Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you choose $xe^x$ ?

Comment: Something I read in my lecture notes, it said that if $Q(x)=4e^x$ then choosing $axe^x$ would be best... I find this quite ad hoc, shame there is no systematic way of finding our the PI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $x$: try a solution of the form $y=x$. Then $y'''-3y''+9y'+13y$ yields $13x+9$, and you can adjust by deducting $9/13$;
- $e^x$: try a solution of the form $y=e^x$. Then $y'''-3y''+9y'+13y$ yields $20e^x$.

Hence

$$y=\frac{x}{13}-\frac9{169}+\frac{e^x}{20}.$$

---

When plugged in the LHS, a polynomial gives a polynomial of the same degree.

When plugged in the LHS, an exponential gives an exponential of the same coefficient, or zero (when the coefficient is a root of the polynomial).

Only in case of a zero you need to multiply by a polynomial of a degree equal to the multiplicity of the root.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution below and contains the Particular Integral.
[image: Solution]